# Android Edittext width automatically changed when input large text

Tags: android, android-activity, android-edittext

i have edittext and when i input some text  width automatically Increased. this is a my edit text xml code

```
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/namefild"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:background="@drawable/edittextbackground"
            android:hint="Name"
            android:paddingLeft="15dp"
            android:textColorHint="#e2e0e0" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

how i can solve my problem? i don't need to change edittext 's width .if anyone knows solution please help me

Comment: How many maximum character you want to see?

Comment: @ツPratikButaniツ i don't know .any size

Comment: then??? how can i tell you? as per my suggestion you have to close this question.

Answer (score 1):

try this property android:layout_width="0dp"

Answer (score 1):

its because the width of EditText is wrap_content. Try using fixed width or match_parent. It should work.

Comment: i also changed it but when i changed it edittext is full width and i don't need to be like this

Comment: If you want your exit text of any fixed width than why not you are using any fix value as width. You can have different values for different density devices.